# Getting Error When Clearing Cells - Simple Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple script that is supposed to clear cells in a sheet.  I have removed all of the script but one line to try and narrow it down but I am still getting We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('QUOTE SHEET');
  sheet.getRange('A30').clearContent();
}
```

I had this working on another sheet in the past.  Am I missing something here?

This one works on a differnt sheet

```
function Clear() {

  //////////////          Clear Discovery Sheet             ///////////////

  var discoverySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Discovery Sheet');
  discoverySheet.getRange('A7').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('E7').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('A15').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('E15').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('A23').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('E23').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('A31').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('E31').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('B2').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('B4').clearContent();
  discoverySheet.getRange('F4').clearContent();

  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Discovery Sheet');
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);
  name.getRange('a38').setValue(email);

  //////////////          Clear Quote Sheet             ///////////////

  var quoteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('QUOTE SHEET');
  quoteSheet.getRange('A17').clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange('A18').clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange('B17').clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange('B18').clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange("E26:E35").clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange("F26:F35").clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange('F22').clearContent();
  quoteSheet.getRange('F23').clearContent();




  //////////////          device payment             ///////////////

  var quoteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('QUOTE SHEET');
  quoteSheet.getRange("E26:E34").setValue('$0.00');  
  quoteSheet.getRange("F26:F34").setValue('$0.00'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("C26:C34").setValue('$0.00');  
  quoteSheet.getRange("A26:A35").setValue('Select Phone Model ');  
  quoteSheet.getRange("A17").setValue('None'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("A18").setValue('None'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("e17").setValue('0%'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("b17").setValue('0'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("b18").setValue('0'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("a21").setValue('Select Plan'); 
  quoteSheet.getRange("F17").setValue("0.00");  
  quoteSheet.getRange("b22").setValue('0%');

    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D26");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B26="N.A",0,if(B26="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A26)),B26/6,B26/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D27");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B27="N.A",0,if(B27="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A27)),B26/6,B27/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D28");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B28="N.A",0,if(B28="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A28)),B28/6,B28/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D29");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B29="N.A",0,if(B29="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A29)),B29/6,B29/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D30");
    cell.setFormula('=if(B30="N.A",0,if(B30="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A30)),B30/6,B30/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D31");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B31="N.A",0,if(B31="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A31)),B31/6,B31/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D32");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B32="N.A",0,if(B32="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A32)),B32/6,B32/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D33");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B33="N.A",0,if(B33="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A33)),B33/6,B33/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D34");
  cell.setFormula('=if(B34="N.A",0,if(B34="CPE/No DPP",0,if(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("watch",A34)),B34/6,B34/24)))');
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B21")
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A21,PLANS!A4:B1000,2,false),0)');



  //////////////          Totals             ///////////////

    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G26");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D26,E26,F26,C26)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G27");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D27,E27,F27,C27)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G28");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D28,E28,F28,C28)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G29");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D29,E29,F29,C29)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G30");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D30,E30,F30,C30)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G31");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D31,E31,F31,C31)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G32");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D32,E32,F32,C32)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G33");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D33,E33,F33,C33)')
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("G34");
  cell.setFormula('=SUM(D34,E34,F34,C34)')



  //////////////          RETAIL PRICE             ///////////////

    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B26");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A26,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B27");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A27,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B28");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A28,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B29");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A29,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B30");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A30,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B31");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A31,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B32");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A32,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B33");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A33,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("B34");
  cell.setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A34,'PHONES 2 (Do Not Edit)'!A:C,2,false),0)")

  //////////////          BUNDLE PACKAGES             ///////////////
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("E18");
  cell.setFormula("=D18-E19")
    var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("D18");
  cell.setFormula('=if(A17="Diamond Package",B17*200,if(A17="Platinum Package",B17*150,0))+if(A18="Diamond Package",B18*200,if(A18="Platinum Package",B18*150,0))')


  //////////////          Name Section             ///////////////

      var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("f4");
  cell.setFormula("='Discovery Sheet'!B2")
      var cell = quoteSheet.getRange("f5");
  cell.setFormula("='Discovery Sheet'!B4")


}
```

UPDATED SCRIPT:

```
function test(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('QUOTE SHEET');

var cell = sheet.getRange("A30:A38");
var cellBC = sheet.getRange("B30:V38");
  var cellEG = sheet.getRange("E30:G38");
      var cellB17_18 = sheet.getRange("B17:B18");
          var cellc17_19 = sheet.getRange("B19:B20"); 
              var celld17_20 = sheet.getRange("B21:B22");
                  var celle17_21 = sheet.getRange("B23:B24");

cell.setValue("Select Phone Model ");
cellBC.setValue("");
  cellEG.setValue("");
      cellB17_18.setValue("");
          cellc17_19.setValue("");
              celld17_20.setValue("");
                  celle17_21.setValue("");


}
```

Comment: While your script is simple, it's *very* inefficient, it will have used your quota. You need to cut down the amount of `getRange()` calls significantly, you can do this by instead defining actual ranges of cells and using `setValues()` and `setFormulas()` rather than doing them one by one.

Comment: @David Morin Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue?

Comment: I copied that small piece of code above and it worked fine for me.  No errors... I've had server errors before and tried again later and it worked...  so might not be your fault??

Comment: So it appears none of my scripts are working with this workbook

Comment: Update:  I copied the workbook and reran it with the script and it is working.  Bizarre for sure

Comment: @ross Would this be what you mean? `function test(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('QUOTE SHEET');
var cell = sheet.getRange("a40");
cell.setValue(100);

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was for some reason my workbook was "corrupt"  I made a copy and used the exact script and it worked for me.  This must have been an issue with Googles side of things.  So if this happens to anyone else try that first.